# Create Custom Image From Username in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, image

- Laravel Version: 8.35.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.0

**Description:**

Hello Friends, I Want to create a custom image of a user from the first letter of the username in Laravel.

How can I Do This?

Plz, Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Imagick to do this

```
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$image->newImage(300, 300, new ImagickPixel( '#F4511E' ));
$draw->setFillColor('white');
/* $draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic'); */
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );
$image->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, 'ABC');

$image->setImageFormat('png');
file_put_contents("abc.png",$image);
```